# Django Sitetree translate

Tags: django, translate, django-sitetree

I have an application with a backend made in Django. The application has the option of the Spanish and English language, where I make the translation of all the sections through a django.po file.

What I want to do is to be able to translate the sitetree (that is, the entire menu) that is made in English to Spanish.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Thank you very much for your time.